# Adding a view between 2 views when one view is aligned to the bottom programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have a relative layout that contains a scrollview that I want to place between 2 other relative layouts.  One of these layouts is aligned to parent bottom.  I would like for it to stay at the bottom.

Here's my code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams formRenderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(formRenderParams);
        formRenderParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, pageButtons.getId());

        //relative is the relative layout that has been aligned to bottom in previous code
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relative.getLayoutParams();
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, r_scroll.getId());
        relative.setLayoutParams(p);


        mainLayout.addView(r_scroll, formRenderParams);
```

pageButtons is Layout A, r_scroll is Layout B, and relative is Layout C.

The problem is that C disappears.  It either disappears with this code, or B overlaps it.  What I want is for B to take up the remaining space, but with no overlapping.

Also here's a picture to show the problem visually:

[image]

Any ideas on what's going on?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    RelativeLayout rlmain= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);

    RelativeLayout rA=new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rA.setId(1);
    rA.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    layoutA.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, rlmain.getId());
    rA.setLayoutParams(layoutA);

    TextView tvA=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvParamA = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvA.setText("This is Layout 1");
    tvA.setLayoutParams(tvParamA);
    rA.addView(tvA);

    RelativeLayout rC=new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutC = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutC.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,rlmain.getId());
    rC.setId(3);
    rC.setLayoutParams(layoutC);
    rC.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));

    TextView tvC=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvParamC = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvC.setText("This is Layout 3");
    tvC.setLayoutParams(tvParamC);
    rC.addView(tvC);

    RelativeLayout rB=new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutB.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rA.getId());
    layoutB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, rC.getId());
    rB.setId(2);
    rB.setLayoutParams(layoutB);
    rB.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));

    ScrollView scroll=new ScrollView(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollB = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    scroll.setLayoutParams(scrollB);
    rB.addView(scroll);

    rlmain.addView(rA);
    rlmain.addView(rB);
    rlmain.addView(rC);
```

rlMain in above code is the RelativeLayout declared in xml file.

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Thanks.  I'll go off this as an example.

Answer (score 1):

just follow the pattern of this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"
        android:layout_above="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` of `formRenderParams` this rule:

```
formRenderParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, relative .getId());
```

and change

```
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, r_scroll.getId());
```

to

```
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

to avoid circular dependencies in layout.

---

**Edit**

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams formRenderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
r_scroll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // this is just to test the guess
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but it didn't work.  r_scroll doesn't appear at all now, but relative does show.  Maybe i'm not showing enough of the code;  I thought I would only show the part that's doing the lifting.

Comment: this is only a guess but it may be due to the fact that ScrollView content is empty at that moment. 
Try to set up the height of r_scroll to MATCH_PARENT instead of WRAP_CONTENT. I've updated answer with such details.